# ObjC: Local variable seems to retain its value across function calls

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, scope, objective-c-blocks, enumeration

I just stumbled across an odd bug in an enumerator I wrote:

```
// typedef for reference
typedef void (^OGWEntityEnumerationBlock)(OGWEntity* entity, BOOL* stop);


-(void) enumerateEntitiesInCategory:(const OGWEntityCategory*)category 
                         usingBlock:(OGWEntityEnumerationBlock)block
{
    BOOL stop;
    NSArray* entitiesInCategory = [_cagetorizedEntities objectForKey:category];

    for (OGWEntity* entity in [entitiesInCategory reverseObjectEnumerator])
    {
        block(entity, &stop);

        if (stop)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

The first use of `enumerateEntitiesInCategory:usingBlock:` works fine. Eventually the caller finds the entity it was searching for and sets the `*stop` parameter to `YES`.

The next use of `enumerateEntitiesInCategory:usingBlock:` immediately exits after the first iteration. Upon closer inspection `stop` is now initialized to `YES` as soon as a previous iteration has set the `*stop` parameter to YES. I have to purposefully initialize the stop variable with `NO` to fix this.

How can this be? I know that the address of the stop variable (perhaps by chance) may have remained the same across invocations which would explain the "old" value to be there. But I was under the impression that ARC ensures uninitialized types are set to 0 respectively `nil`, so shouldn't it set the BOOL to NO every time the function is invoked?

Interestingly, if I use `__block BOOL stop;` the stop variable is **always** initialized to YES according to the debugger, even during the first time (again, probably by chance depending on whatever uninitialized value was at that address).

This seems to indicate that I may be wrongly assuming that uninitialized variables are zero-ed and ARC - perhaps ARC really only cares about initializing object types with nil but doesn't care about integral types? Or is this only true for ivars but not local variables?

Comment: As Martin R mentioned in his answer, the variable needs to be initialized. As to why it seems to retain its value in the absence of a (re-)initialization, it may simply be that you call the method (_not_ function) at the same level of the call tree, and so the local variable gets allocated the same slot on the stack that it had before. Result: it "sees" the same value that it had at the last call.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Only pointers to Objective-C objects are initialized to `nil` with ARC
(and all instance variables of an object), but not local variables in general.
So you have to initialize the boolean variable with

```
BOOL stop = NO;
```

Comment: Thanks for confirming, I think I better recheck my code for other possibly uninitialized non-id types.